# EntityFramework 6.4.4 and SQL aggregate user defined function with multiple parameters

Tags: c#, entity-framework-6, user-defined-functions

I have an aggregate UDF that I would like to use in Entity Framework's linq to SQL. Another function with just one argument works fine. If define two arguments (collection and a string) and try to execute, it fails with exception:

```
System.Data.Entity.Core.EntityCommandCompilationException: An error occurred while preparing the command definition. See the inner exception for details. ---> System.ArgumentException: The expression list has an incorrect number of elements.
Parameter name: argument
   at System.Data.Entity.Core.Common.CommandTrees.ExpressionBuilder.Internal.EnumerableValidator`3.Validate(IEnumerable`1 argument, String argumentName, Int32 expectedElementCount, Boolean allowEmpty, Func`3 map, Func`2 collect, Func`3 deriveName)
   at System.Data.Entity.Core.Common.CommandTrees.ExpressionBuilder.Internal.EnumerableValidator`3.Validate()
   at System.Data.Entity.Core.Common.CommandTrees.ExpressionBuilder.Internal.ArgumentValidation.CreateExpressionList(IEnumerable`1 arguments, String argumentName, Int32 expectedElementCount, Action`2 validationCallback)
.....
```

I understand this feature should be implemented by this pull: https://github.com/dotnet/ef6/pull/90 . So what am I missing?

My code:

```
   

     //Defining function for linq:
        public class CustomSqlFunctions
        {
            [DbFunction("CodeFirstDatabaseSchema", "GROUP_CONCAT_D")]
            public static string GROUP_CONCAT_D(IEnumerable source, string delimeter)
            {
                throw new NotSupportedException("Direct calls are not supported.");
            }
        }
    
    //adding function to model
      public class AddGROUP_CONCAT_DFunction : IStoreModelConvention
        {
            public void Apply(EdmModel item, DbModel dbModel)
            {
                var edmStringType2 = dbModel.ProviderManifest.GetStoreType(TypeUsage.CreateDefaultTypeUsage(PrimitiveType.GetEdmPrimitiveType(PrimitiveTypeKind.String))).EdmType;
                CollectionType edmStringListType2 = edmStringType2.GetCollectionType();
                
                string schema = item.Container.EntitySets.Select(s => s.Schema).Distinct().SingleOrDefault();
               
                EdmFunction GROUP_CONCAT_Dfunction = EdmFunction.Create(nameof(CustomSqlFunctions.GROUP_CONCAT_D), "CodeFirstDatabaseSchema", item.DataSpace, new EdmFunctionPayload
                {
                    ParameterTypeSemantics = ParameterTypeSemantics.AllowImplicitConversion,
                    IsAggregate = true,
                    IsComposable = true,
                    StoreFunctionName = nameof(CustomSqlFunctions.GROUP_CONCAT_D),
    
                    Schema = schema,
                    ReturnParameters = new[] { FunctionParameter.Create("ReturnType", edmStringType2, ParameterMode.ReturnValue) },
                    Parameters = new[] {
                        FunctionParameter.Create("input", edmStringListType2, ParameterMode.In),
                        FunctionParameter.Create("delimeter", PrimitiveType.GetEdmPrimitiveType(PrimitiveTypeKind.String).GetEdmPrimitiveType(), ParameterMode.In)
                        },
                    
                }, null);
    
                item.AddItem(GROUP_CONCAT_Dfunction);
    
                dbModel.Compile();
            }
    
        }
    
    //in my DbContext  class
            protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
            {
                ...
                modelBuilder.Conventions.Add(new AddGROUP_CONCAT_DFunction());
                ...
            }
```